# How to adjust the parameter of TextureCoordinateScaling

Tags: plotting, image-processing, image, textures

I wanna draw a picture like this
[image]

This is my current work,First get the texture of picture

```
text = "不
  上
  班
  你
  咬
  我
  啊";
textimg = 
  Style[text, 70] // 
   Rasterize[#, "Image", Background -> Transparent, 
     ImageSize -> Large] &;
alphaback = 
 SetAlphaChannel[textimg, Binarize[textimg, 0.99] // ColorNegate]
```

[image]

```
img=ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]], z}, {\[Theta], 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, {z, 0, 0.5}, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 Background -> White, PlotStyle -> {Texture[alphaback]}, 
 TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#1, #3} &), 
 TextureCoordinateScaling -> False]//Image
```

[image]

Get the shadow

```
shadow = ImageReflect[img, Top -> Bottom] // MeanFilter[#, 15] &
```

[image]

Then the result is

```
ImageAssemble[
 List /@ ConformImages[{img // ImageCrop, shadow}, {Max, Min}]]
```

[image]

How bad the work it is!And my import quetion is how can I control the parameter to attach the texture to the ring normally.Could anybody have a try to draw this picture?

Comment: Try giving `{#4, #5} &` (or the reverse) as the `TextureCoordinateFunction`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for your comment.But the change have doesn't work~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question "how can I control the parameter to attach the texture to the ring?" - well it takes a bit of trial and error.  There is some documentation on the `TextureCoordinateFunction`, and we can work the rest out ourselves.

We want the horizontal and vertical directions of the image to go with the z axis and the angular coordinate.  These correspond to the two arguments of the parametric plot.  Also, you definitely want to set `TextureCoordinateScaling` to `True`.

```
textimg = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBrNt.png"];
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[θ], Sin[θ], z}, {θ, 
   0, 2 π}, {z, 0, 0.5}, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> False, Background -> White, PlotStyle -> {Texture[textimg]},
   TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5, #4} &), 
  TextureCoordinateScaling -> True]
```

Next I try to get the object oriented properly, I do this with my mouse, then I have this function to get the viewpoint I want,

```
viewpoint[graphics_] := 
 FilterRules[{AbsoluteOptions[graphics]}, {ViewPoint, ViewVertical, 
   ViewCenter}]
```

I rotate the image by hand, apply this function and get a viewpoint, so that in the future it always comes out right.  I get this image now

[image]

But I want the characters to only show up on part of the circle, so I adjust the range of θ values to between $3\pi/5$ and $6\pi/5$

Here's what I came up with in the end, after adding in a couple circles for the ring, and the shadow

```
textimg = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBrNt.png"];

Module[{R = 1.4, innerring, outerring, textring, viewpoint, baseimg, 
  shadow},
 innerring = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{R Cos[θ], R Sin[θ], 0.5}, {θ,
     0, 2 π},
   Mesh -> None,
   Boxed -> False,
   Axes -> False,
   Background -> White,
   PlotStyle -> Black];
 outerring = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{R Cos[θ], R Sin[θ], 
    0.0}, {θ, -5 π/8, 2 π/5},
   PlotStyle -> Black];
 textring = 
  ParametricPlot3D[{R Cos[θ], R Sin[θ], z}, {θ, 
    3 π/5, 6 π/5}, {z, 0, 0.5}, Mesh -> None,
   PlotStyle -> {Texture[textimg]},
   TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#5, #4} &),
   TextureCoordinateScaling -> True];
 viewpoint = {ViewCenter -> {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, 
   ViewPoint -> {-3.2, 0.38, 1.44}, 
   ViewVertical -> {.23, -0.89, -0.57}};
 baseimg = Show[
   innerring,
   outerring,
   textring,
   viewpoint, ImageSize -> 500, PlotRange -> {All, All, {-1, 1}}];
 shadow = ImageReflect[baseimg, Top -> Bottom]~MeanFilter~5;
 GraphicsColumn[ImageCrop /@ {baseimg, shadow}]
 ]
```

[image]